# segment в codeigniter

Tags: php, url, codeigniter

Помогите пожалуйста решить такой вопрос.

Есть функции в контроллере:

```
        public function index() {

            $compname = $this->uri->segment(2); 

            Код.....

            }else{
                    $this->listing();
            }
    }   



    function photos ($compname) {

            Код......

            }else{
               redirect("listing");
            }
    }
```

Сейчас работает так:

site.ru/company/companyname - название компании

site.ru/company/photos/companyname - фото компании

Как сделать чтобы photos был после имени? т.е. так:

site.ru/company/companyname/photos

Пробовал различные подстановки сегмента, не помогает. Не пойму как решить этот вопрос. Спасибо.

Comment: Почитайте про Роутинг в документации. Подробнее с телефона не могу.

Comment: Пробовал различные варианты, не получается :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-умолчанию адреса роутятся таким образом: 
в 1м сегменте - имя контроллера
во 2м - имя actions (метода этого контроллера)
в 3м - параметры метода

В вашем случае:

`site.ru/company/photos/companyname`

**company** - контроллер `application/controller/company.php`

**photos** - метод `function photos($compname) {}`

**companyname** - параметр метода `$compname`

для того, чтобы поменять местами расположение action и параметра нужно изменить правила роутинга. Делается это в файле `application/config/routes.php`

```
// первый (:any) - это 'photos', мы переставляем его в конец ($1)
// второй (:any) - это 'companyname' - ставим его перед photos ($2)
$route['company/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'company/$2/$1';
```

Учтите только, что правила роутинга в этом файле срабатывают по принципе "какое первое совпадет - то и сработает". То есть если перед этим правилом встретится какое-то более общее, например `$route['(:any)']` - выполнится оно и до нашего правила дело не дойдет.

И еще, приведённая мной строка будет менять местами все actions, например:

site.ru/company/companyname/blog

site.ru/company/companyname/forum

и т.д.

Если стоит задача сменить только photos:

```
$route['company/photos/(:any)'] = 'company/$1/photos';
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за такой развернутый ответ.